# Django and south upgrade

Tags: django, django-south

My projects is running on Django 1.3 and mysql on production.But I am using sqlite in my development environment. I am upgrading Django to 1.6 directly. Do we need to do some up gradations in south also?Will the up gradation of Django will effect my migrations also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for the help.
I got the answer.I had to upgrade my south to South-0.8.x. Its clearly written in south documentation that in this version they solve the problem with [sqlite](http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/releasenotes/0.8.2.html#sqlite-fixes) db.

Answer (score 0):

migrations becomes a part of the django stack [from version 1.7 onwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/#a-brief-history) (currently in development), so unless you're also upgrading the south version, there isn't any special changes the upgrade will require as far as south is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problems due to the fact that you are upgrading Django and South is only a "library".

You can also read:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/migrations/

And try it first on the development environment.